# CNN forward function , AutoTuning the number of layers

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, optuna, auto-tuning

```
class ConvolutionalNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, trial):
        # we optimize the number of layers, hidden units and dropout ratio in each layer.
        n_layers = self.trial.suggest_int("n_layers", 1, 5)
        p = self.trial.suggest_uniform("dropout_1{}".format(i), 0, 1.0)
        layers = []
        for i in range(n_layers):
            self.out_features = self.trial.suggest_int("n_units_1{}".format(i), 16, 160,step =2)
            kernel_size = trial.suggest_int('kernel_size', 2, 7)
            layers.append(nn.Conv1d(1, self.out_features,kernel_size,1))
            layers.append(nn.RReLU())
            layers.append(nn.BatchNorm1d(self.out_features)
            layers.append(nn.Dropout(p))

            self.in_features = self.out_features

        layers.append(nn.Conv1d(self.in_features, 16,kernel_size,1))
        layers.append(nn.RReLU())
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)
```

As you can see above, I did some Optuna tuning of parameters , including tuning on the number of layers.

```
def forward(self,x):
    # shape x for conv 1d op
    x = x.view(-1, 1, self.in_features)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = F.rrelu(x)
    x = F.max_pool1d(x, 64, 64)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = F.rrelu(x)
    x = F.max_pool1d(x, 64, 64)
    x = x.view(-1, self.n_conv)

    x = self.dp(x)
    x = self.fc3(x)
    x = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
    return x
```

I now need to do the same for the forward function above, I did the pseudo code below but it won't run, kindly advise how. The main issue is to incorporate the for loop function for the forward function.

```
def forward(self,x):
    # shape x for conv 1d op
    x = x.view(-1, 1, self.in_features)
    for i in range(n_layers):
        layers.append(self.conv1(x))
        layers.append(F.rrelu(x))
        layers.append(F.max_pool1d(x, 64, 64))
    x = x.view(-1, self.n_conv)
    x = self.dp(x)
    x = self.fc3(x)
    #x = F.sigmoid(x)
    x = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
    return x
```

Comment: Can you share the error/problem you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

there are a bunch of errors that make it hard to understand what you intended to do :

- Why would you build a `nn.Sequential` model in the `__init__`and not use it ?
- What is this `return` instruction in `__init__` ??
- The successive convolution layers you create do not have matching channel sizes (`in_channels` is always 1). The `out_feature` of one iteration should be the `in_features` of the next iteration
- Your pseudocode for the `forward` function appends tensors in a `layers` list (which you did not declare btw) and then does not use this list.
- At the beginning of the `forward`, you reshape your input with `x = x.view(-1, 1, self.in_features)`, but at that point `in_features` does not match at all the numer of input channels for the first convolution layer.

long story short : correct all the above errors, and then something like :

```
class ConvolutionalNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, trial):
        # do your stuff here ...
        self._model = nn.Sequential(*layers)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self._model(x)
```

should work